# Setting Android drop down navigation spinner position

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I have an application that uses [Drop-down navigation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) and the action bar title may change depending on the current fragment. Since the titles are of varying length this causes the drop down spinner to continually move around the action bar rather than staying stationary (see the picture below). Is there any way to force the spinner to say on the left side of the action bar or to force it's position regardless of the title length?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The attribute from within the layout within your ActionBar showAsAction set to always should be enough to keep the spinner in the ActionBar visible regardless of whether or not the text runs into it.  The text will be clipped when it is long, but if you don't have space, then you don't have space.

```
<item android:id="@+id/spinnerItem"
      ...
      android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

**Edit:**

If you are not dealing with a layout file, but are still using a built-in ActionBar item, then you can grab that element by its id (if you have that available in some manner) and then set the attribute within the code as you would a normal menu component.  I am not familiar with creating menu items through code cause I usually do so in layout files for these, but I am sure you can grab its id when you introduce it and store it somewhere for use during the menu setup phase, or at a later given point in time if you'd like in order to set this attribute later.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menuF)
{
    spinnerMenuItem_ = menuF.findItem(R.id.spinnerId);
    spinnerMenuItem_.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
}
```

Comment: I'm not using a layout to define my action bar so how do I tie the bar provided by Android with the custom layout?